# Extract frames from a .FLA adobe video

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming

I have an flash `.fla` video file (I guess an Adobe video) and one `.js` and `.html` file. I need to extract frames from it but VLC doesn't do it, any other program I could use? Is it possible to extract frames from a `.fla`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash video is in FLV format. If you have an FLA then that's a Flash Project file. It must be opened with **Adobe Animate** or **Flash CS** software and from there you click options to export as video file (`.mp4` / `.mov`) or export for Flash Player plugin format (as `.swf` format) viewed in browser.

While looking at the `.html` source code, you should also word search for `.swf` to see what file the web page loads as Flash content (`.swf`).

To convert SWF to video file, use either FFmpeg, or even do it with Animate/Flash CS.